# get image pixel location using coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations, image-processing

I am working on a small project and have to draw the location of the indoor map. I have a mapping between some points on an image from pixel to coordinates **(point, Latitude, Longitude)**:

1. 55.9444578385393,-3.1866151839494705
2. 55.94444244275808,-3.18672649562358860
3. 55.94452336441765,-3.1866540759801865
4. 55.94452261340533,-3.1867526471614838

Each of these points corresponds to the pixel location on an image, **(x, y)**, where (0,0) is the top left corner:

1. 1428.5, 552.5
2. 1092.5, 537.5
3. 1392.5, 168.5
4. 1140.5, 96.5

**P.S.** 43.1 pixels map to 1 meter

Is there a quick way to **calculate the pixel location** given new coordinate, let us say, (latitude) 55.94445295695079, (longitude)-3.186666816473007 if I know that an image is 2060px(width) by 1109px(height)?

I was trying to the position of a pixel by creating a proportional relation between the coordinates and pixels, but that gave me non-sensible results.

[image: An image of with points marked]

Comment: The data don't seem to make much sense.  Points with nearly identical latitude or longitude have wildly different pixel coordinates.  How are the latitudes and longitudes arrived at?

Comment: Latitude and longitude represent a real location on the map, whereas an image is just a small patch of the map, with high resolution (hence the widely different pixel coordinates).

Comment: I'd say it depends what you consider "quick". At the scale of one building, I would have thought you could probably obtain an affine relationship between pixel location and latitude/longitude. Could you share your current approach, and why you think the results are non-sensible?

Comment: But they aren't consistent, which is why you are getting nonsense when you try to map to pixels.  Did you use GPS to get the latitude and longitude, by any chance?  For example the longitudes of point 3 to point 1 is much closer than the longitude of point 1 to point 2, but the y pxiels values are much farther apart.

Comment: @saulspatz I didn't take a close look at his data, but nothing indicates the picture has north/south or east/west alignment (at least I don't know where north is in his building). So a difference in longitude may have more impact in x-coordinate than y-coordinate in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the abscissa/ordinate (in pixels) and the longitude/latitude of any three points (preferably far apart).

The transformation relations are affine:

$$x=a u+b v+c,\\y=d u+e v+f.$$

You have two independent systems of 3 equations in 3 unknowns, which you can solve for $a,b,c,d,e,f$.

You can obtain the inverse transform by solving the equations anew with the roles of $x,y$ and $u,v$ exchanged.

Comment: ...or use all points, and solve the system of equations using least squares. If the data is perfect, there is no difference, but if there's a bit of noise, using all points will make it a bit more robust.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: technically speaking, least-squares fitting is not robust. Least absolute deviations or trimmed least-squares or others might be preferable.

Comment: True, those are robust if you expect outliers.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: you mentioned robustness.

Comment: I’m not disagreeing with you. I was just thinking of “robustness against small measurement errors” rather than “robustness against outliers”. Your suggested fit methods are the better choice, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a linear model for each coordinate, here's a little python script

```
import numpy as np

coords = [
    [55.9444578385393, -3.1866151839494705],
    [55.94444244275808, -3.18672649562358860],
    [55.94452336441765, -3.1866540759801865], 
    [55.94452261340533,-3.1867526471614838]]

pixels = [
    [1428.5, 552.5],
    [1092.5, 537.5],
    [1392.5, 168.5],
    [1140.5, 96.5]]

coords = np.array(coords)
pixels = np.array(pixels)

al, bl = np.polyfit(coords[ : , 0], pixels[ : , 0], 1)
ab, bb = np.polyfit(coords[ : , 1], pixels[ : , 1], 1)
```

This is an example

```
l, b = 55.944457, -3.1866151839
pl = al * l + bl
pb = ab * b + bb


print 'pixels({}, {}) = ({}, {})'.format(l, b, pl, pb)
```

with output

```
pixels(55.944457, -3.1866151839) = (1246.50869663, 444.441180377)
```